Input de Búsqueda no Retorna los Datos Esperados: ¿Cómo Solucionarlo?
Estoy utilizando el componente Command de ShadCN para crear un input de búsqueda dentro de un Dialog. El problema surge cuando escribo un término de búsqueda, por ejemplo, el título del post The Future of Electric Cars: A Sustainable Revolution. Si escribo parcialmente el término, como The Future, no aparece ningún resultado en el momento. Sin embargo, si cierro el Dialog y lo vuelvo a abrir, entonces ingreso el mismo término y la búsqueda funciona correctamente.
Parece que el input no actualiza los resultados en tiempo real mientras el Dialog está abierto. ¿Cómo puedo solucionar este comportamiento para que los resultados de la búsqueda se actualicen dinámicamente sin necesidad de cerrar y reabrir el Dialog?
Este es un componente para buscar posts que estan creados con sanity. y los busco mediante su coincidencia exacta del title

Componente Search
export function CommandSearch() {

    // State for Open and Close Modal
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

    // State for Saving the Search Term
    const [SEARCH, setSEARCH] = React.useState(undefined);

    // The `useDebouncedValue` hook is used to delay the update of `searchTerm`.
    // This prevents unnecessary renders or API calls while the user is typing.
    // The `300` value specifies a debounce time of 300ms.
    const debouncedSearchTerm = useDebouncedValue(SEARCH, 500);

     // Actualiza el estado de la búsqueda cuando el valor debounced cambie
     React.useEffect(() => {
        setSEARCH(debouncedSearchTerm);
    }, [debouncedSearchTerm]);

    // Hook Function for Run the fectch that have a query for find a post
    const { data, isLoading } = useSearchPosts(debouncedSearchTerm);

    // Navigation and router push after click a post
    const router = useRouter();

    // Effect hook to toggle the search dialog when the "Ctrl+K" or "Cmd+K" keyboard shortcut is pressed.
    // It listens for the keydown event and opens/closes the dialog accordingly.
    React.useEffect(() => {
        const down = (e) => {
            if (e.key === 'k' && (e.metaKey || e.ctrlKey)) {
                e.preventDefault();
                setOpen((open) => !open); // Toggle the dialog's open state.
            }
        };
        document.addEventListener('keydown', down); // Attach the event listener on mount.
        return () => document.removeEventListener('keydown', down); // Cleanup the event listener on unmount.
    }, []);


    return (
        <>
            <Button
                variant="outline"
                className={cn('relative h-9 w-9 p-0 xl:h-10 xl:w-60 xl:justify-start xl:px-3 xl:py-2', open && 'border-primary')}
                onClick={() => setOpen(true)}
            >
                <Search className="h-4 w-4 xl:mr-2" />
                <span className="hidden xl:inline-flex">Search posts...</span>
                <kbd className="pointer-events-none absolute right-1.5 top-2 hidden h-6 select-none items-center gap-1 rounded border bg-muted px-1.5 font-mono text-[10px] font-medium opacity-100 xl:flex">
                    <span className="text-xs">ctrl</span>K
                </kbd>
            </Button>
            <CommandDialog
                open={open}
                onOpenChange={(isOpen) => {
                    setOpen(isOpen);
                    if (!isOpen) setSEARCH(undefined); // Clear the search state only when closing the dialog.
                }}
                className="w-auto max-w-[90vw] p-4"
            >
                <CommandInput
                    placeholder="Search posts..."
                    value={SEARCH}
                    onValueChange={setSEARCH}
                />
                <CommandList>
                    {isLoading ? (
                        <div className="flex items-center justify-center py-6">
                            <Loader2 className="h-6 w-6 animate-spin text-primary" />
                        </div>
                    ) : data?.length > 0 ? (
                        <CommandGroup heading="Search Results">
                            {data.map((post) => (
                                <PostItem
                                    key={post._id}
                                    post={post}
                                    onSelect={(slug) => {
                                        setOpen(false); // Close the dialog.
                                        setSEARCH(undefined); // Clear the search state.
                                        router.push(`/${slug}`); // Navigate to the selected post.
                                    }}
                                />
                            ))}
                        </CommandGroup>
                    ) : (
                        <CommandEmpty>
                            No results found.
                        </CommandEmpty>
                    )}
                </CommandList>
            </CommandDialog>
        </>
    );
};

Componente PostItem se ve asi
// Subcomponente para cada post
export const PostItem = ({ post, onSelect }) => (
    <CommandItem
        key={post._id}
        onSelect={() => onSelect(post.slug.current)}
        className="group relative flex items-center gap-4 p-4 cursor-pointer w-full"
    >
        <div className="w-24 h-24 flex-shrink-0 overflow-hidden rounded-md relative">
            <Image
                src={post.mainImage}
                alt={post.alt || 'Post Image'}
                layout="fill"
                objectFit="cover"
                className="w-full h-full"
            />
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-col justify-between w-full">
            <div className="font-bold text-lg text-primary break-words">
                {post.title}
            </div>
            <div className="flex items-center gap-2 mt-2 text-sm text-muted-foreground">
                <Image
                    src={post.avatar}
                    alt={`${post.authorName}'s Avatar`}
                    width={24}
                    height={24}
                    className="rounded-full"
                />
                <span>By {post.authorName}</span>
                <span className="mx-2">•</span>
                <span>{dateUtils(post.publishedAt)}</span>
            </div>
            <div className="mt-3 text-xs text-muted-foreground">
                Categories:{' '}
                <span className="text-primary">
                    {post.categories?.join(', ') || 'None'}
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </CommandItem>
);

Funcion que ejecuta la query
export function useSearchPosts(SEARCH) {
    return useQuery({
        queryKey: ['posts', SEARCH],
        queryFn: async () => {
            if (!SEARCH) return [];

            const data = await client.fetch(SEARCH_QUERY, { SEARCH: `${SEARCH}*` });

            return data;
        },
        enabled: !!SEARCH
        refetchOnWindowFocus: false
    });
}

SEARCH_QUERY
export const SEARCH_POSTS = `
  *[_type == "post" && (title match $SEARCH || categories[]->title match $SEARCH || author->name match $SEARCH) && !(_id in path("drafts.**"))] {
    _id,
    title,
    slug {
      current
    },
    "categories": categories[]->title,
    "authorName": author->name,
    "avatar": author->image.asset->url,
    publishedAt,
    "mainImage": mainImage.asset->url,
    "alt": mainImage.alt,
  }
`;


La version de shadcn que estoy usando es shadcn@2.1.7 y el dialog es "@radix-ui/react-dialog": "^1.1.2", en tu proyecto veo que la version del dialog es la "@radix-ui/react-dialog": "^1.1.3", ahora no se porque tienes la 1.1.3, yo instale el dialog con npx shadcn@latest add command

La diferencia a las versiones quizas se deba a lo siguiente, cuando comenze el repo, hice uso de npx create-next-app@latest para crear un nuevo proyecto de nextjs en eso me di cuenta mas tarde que la version que tenia en next y react eran diferentes, entonces lo reduje a la version en como esta en mi portfolio, pero se me olvido reducir la de radix, no se si por haber instalado react 19 se deba la diferencia de versiones en radix

Bien, te comparto las versiones que estoy usando : "next": "15.0.2", "react": "19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028",, trata de re-instalar npx shadcn@latest add command en algun punto durante la instalacion te va a preguntar esto: How would you like to proceed?le das la opcion › Use --legacy-peer-deps, vamos a ver si con eso te instala la version 1.1.2 y ya jala, mas información aquí

ok el ya quedo @radix-ui/react-dialog": "^1.1.2 pero aun asi esto quedo igual.
